# How should i implement flat app templates custom date field in my php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I get the date values when datepicker is getting generated by div class ?

```
<div id="example-advanced-daterangepicker" class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    <span id="date_custom"></span>
    <b class="caret"></b> 
</div>
```

so how can i get the value from it?

Comment: What library you are using as `daterangepicker`?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja im actually using a flatapp templates , they created it by using jquery